# The Upcoming 10 Year Travel.SE Anniversary

Tags: discussion, community

Travel.SE is turning ten years old! (If you’re curious, you can see [our very first question here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1/101) - unfortunately it was closed, not a great start, but [our first non-closed question is here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2/101).) To celebrate, Stack Exchange is collecting some thoughts for a blog post to celebrate us and other communities that are turning ten this quarter.

For this blog post, Stack Exchange is looking for a few possible ideas:

```
A brief history of Travel.SE
Thoughts on what makes Travel.SE special
Any interesting/fun/memorable stories or experiences from Travel.SE
What drew you to Travel.SE in the first place, and/or why you keep coming back
```

In the answer space below, feel free to address any of the above questions—and anything similar you might want to add!—that you think could have a spot in the blog post. Once we’ve collected the material, we can collaborate to determine how best to share the information.

Even if you just have a fun travel story, or memory of the site - please share it below.  Also share ideas of how we could celebrate? A bounty bonanza? A clean up of unanswered questions? A competition?

Lastly, we can opt to have a temporary “Ten-Year Anniversary” banner on our site; the banner will last for one month. Please vote on [this answer below](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6970/101) to help determine if we want this temporary banner.

Expect more information soon. But in the meantime, congratulations and thanks for being such a great community!

Your mods, [Ankur Banerjee, JoErNanO, JohnathanReez, Mark Mayo and Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)

Answer (score 13):

**“Ten-Year Anniversary” Banner Voting**

**Upvote** this answer if you want the temporary banner.

**Downvote** this answer if you do not want the temporary banner.

Comment: The banner is nice, but I was briefly confused because it didn't tell me that it was for Travel.SE's ten-year anniversary, and I couldn't figure out if it was for all of SE's anniversary, Travel's anniversary, my user account's anniversary, etc... It might be better if it was more clear what anniversary it's for.

Comment: Would also be nice if it was clickable to the blogpost (once it exists)